# Was the Mahabharata war mentioned in the Vedas, and are the claims of this article true?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, history

https://bsvprasad.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/some-arguments-in-favour-of-an-early-date-for-the-mahabharata-war/

As claimed in this article, the names of the Pandavas were actually Ambarisha, Bhayamana, Rjrashwa, Suradhasa and Sahadeva respectively. They all had a shared wife called Ghosha and Krishna was mentioned as Shouradeva. Is this actually mentioned in the Vedas or is this just fake?